# jq - in for loop, create a single new array, then append key/value pairs

Tags: bash, jq

I need to loop through an array (of AWS instance Ids'), then pull tags out and add them into an array using jq.

I have variables defining my needs. In this case:

```
VolumeId
Tag1Value
Tag2Value
Tag3Value
```

They change as I iterate through in a for loop. I know how to create a new array:

```
jq -n --arg v "$VolumeId" '[{"VolumeId": $v}]'
```

However this creates a new JSON array every time. I need it created once, and then append to it as I progress through the loop.

The output I am looking for is a newly create JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "VolumeId": $VolumeId,
    "Tag1": $Tag1Value,
    "Tag2": $Tag2Value,
    "Tag3": $Tag3Value
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": $VolumeId,
    "Tag1": $Tag1Value,
    "Tag2": $Tag2Value,
    "Tag3": $Tag3Value
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": $VolumeId,
    "Tag1": $Tag1Value,
    "Tag2": $Tag2Value,
    "Tag3": $Tag3Value
  }
]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing how a stream of values (here, a stream of arrays) can be combined into a JSON array of objects:

```
(cat << EOF
["VolumeId1", "Tag1Value1", "Tag2Value1", "Tag3Value1"]
["VolumeId2", "Tag1Value2", "Tag2Value2", "Tag3Value2"]
["VolumeId3", "Tag1Value3", "Tag2Value3", "Tag3Value3"]
EOF
) | jq -s 'map( {VolumeId: .[0], Tag1Value: .[1], Tag2Value: .[2],  Tag3Value: .[3] }) '
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "VolumeId": "VolumeId1",
    "Tag1Value": "Tag1Value1",
    "Tag2Value": "Tag2Value1",
    "Tag3Value": "Tag3Value1"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "VolumeId2",
    "Tag1Value": "Tag1Value2",
    "Tag2Value": "Tag2Value2",
    "Tag3Value": "Tag3Value2"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "VolumeId3",
    "Tag1Value": "Tag1Value3",
    "Tag2Value": "Tag2Value3",
    "Tag3Value": "Tag3Value3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks @peak, it works but there's a problem. As I'm iterating through a for loop... I get new arrays every time. Any way to make it 1 array?

Comment: The idea is to pipe the output of the entire "for" loop to jq.  Along the lines of (for ....; do ... done) | jq -s ...

Comment: Also (and apologies for not making my origin question clear), I would need to assign the new array to a variable so I can merge it with another array later. ` | new_array=$(jq -s 'map({ VolumeId: .[0] ....` doesn't work

Comment: I didn't manage to assign it to a variable straight away, but I did pipe the output of the command `| jq ...` to a temporary file, and then `my_array=$(cat /my/tmp/file)`. This works, but if you know a better way not using a temp file then would love to hear from you. Thanks very much for your help

Comment: If you really want to assign the entire array to a single shell variable, you would write something like `VAR=$( (for ...) | jq -s ...)` but this is beginning to look too complicated.  Using bash, you might consider assigning to a bash array variable .... but I suspect you'd be better off using jq more effectively.